# Add Multiple prefixes in order in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, prefix

I don't know a lot in Excel but I want to add Multiple prefixes in Excel and let them loop until the number of cells ends.

I used this Formula, but it picks them randomly:

```
(=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1, 3),"DR. ","SM. ","FG. ")&" "&A1
```

---

Example output I want :

```
Input: ---------> Output:
A                  DR. A
B                  SM. B
C                  FG. C
D                  DR. D
E                  SM. E
F                  FG. F
```

Comment: `=(MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1)&" "&A1`

Comment: What if I want to add a string??

A -------> DR. A
B -------> SM. B
C -------> DR. C
D ------> SM. D

Comment: sorry i didn't word my question right, I want to add a string not a number i thought they were the same process but turns out they aren't. Editing the question rn.

Comment: You may try this, `=CHOOSE(MOD((ROW()-1),3)+1,"DR. ","SM. ","FG. ")&A1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may ***try*** this, using `CHOOSE()` & `MOD()`

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=CHOOSE(MOD((ROW()-1),3)+1,"DR. ","SM. ","FG. ")&A1
```

Or, if one has access to **O365** and presently in **Insiders, Beta Channel Version**, may try this as well, using `CHOOSECOLS()`

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=CHOOSECOLS({"DR. ","SM. ","FG. "},MOD((ROW()-1),3)+1)&A1
```